# How to improve accuracy with Google Speech-to-Text API version v1?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm currently working on integrating the Google Speech-to-Text API v1 into my application for audio transcription. While the API generally provides decent results, I'm looking for ways to improve the accuracy of the transcriptions, especially for challenging audio recordings.

```
RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED)
                    .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRate)
                    .setAudioChannelCount(channelCount)
                    .setLanguageCode("en-US").build();
```

This is my RecognitionConfig configuration.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on techniques or configurations that can help me achieve better results with the API.

Audio link file :

https://storage.googleapis.com/sharedpro_gogole_bucket/audio/audio-file.wav

response : hello my name is renisha and working as a software quality assurance in turn in shedrow technology from past one month.

Comment: How is it not providing good results? Is it within a specific context? What types of recordings? Have you looked at Model Adaptation? Are you using latest_long or latest_short (as appropriate)? Also have you tried v2?

Comment: I am exploring google speech to text API and I pass conversation of two person in speech to text API and I don't know much about Model Adaption or latest_long or latest_short and speech to text V2 version. Can you give any reference or example or documentation so that help to resolve this issue.

Comment: I upload a audio a link and response above in description .

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs ... https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices-provide-speech-data ... https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/adaptation-model ... https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/latest-models

Comment: Now, I am implementing the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API v2 version using client libraries. However, I am facing difficulty in finding the recognizerId field and understanding how to obtain it.
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs/libraries#client-libraries-resources-java
 
@MyNameIsCaleb